# JQuery BlockUI plugin and Angular: Display ajax call time as incremented seconds in place of spinner image

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, jquery-blockui

I'm trying to display the ajax call's execution time rather than a standard ajax spinner.  Im using JQuery's BlockUI plugin.  I've thought about doing the following:

```
$.blockUI.defaults = {
    // message displayed when blocking (use null for no message)
    message:  $scope.runningTime,
```

and then somewhere like

```
 $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI); // add code to increment $scope.runningTime
//and do $scope.$apply();
```

I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with the following solution:

```
<div id="runningTime" style="display:none">
{[{runningTime}]} seconds
</div>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.blockUI.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  var $scope = angular.element($("body")).scope();
  $scope.start_time = new Date().getTime();
  $scope.intervalFn = null;

  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $.blockUI({ message: $("#runningTime") });
    $scope.intervalFn = setInterval(function(){
      var ms = new Date().getTime() - $scope.start_time;
      $scope.runningTime = (ms/1000) % 60;
      try {
        $scope.$apply();
      } catch(err) {
        //do-nothing for now
      }

    },1000);


  });

  $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $.unblockUI();
    clearInterval($scope.intervalFn);
  });
});  
</script>
```